# Не видит Twisted

Tags: python, импорт, pip, twisted

```
File "twisted.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
  File "/home/nitron/Projects/mes/mes/twisted.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted.internet'; 'twisted' is not a package
```

Код:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print('New client connected')
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1234").listen(EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

В pip установлен.

Comment: Запускаемый файл не должен иметь такое же имя, как импортируемый модуль.

Comment: Твою же .... Глупейшая ошибка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переименуйте имя файла с `twisted.py` в `any_other_name.py`